# Magento 2 get cart items in block class

Tags: magento2, blocks

I have created block for sidebar.

I have added below code in my block for compare products. It's working fine

```
<div class="block widget block-compare">
    <div class="block-title">
    </div>
    {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/sidebar.phtml" /}}
</div>
```

I got output like this: http://prntscr.com/n4jcsj

Now i want to show shopping cart items there above compare. Can anyone help me with this.

I also try with minicart but it is not working as per my requirement. It gives me only link of minicart. I need to show content of minicart. I used this code in block.

```
<div class="minicart">
    <div> 
        {{block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="mini_cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml"}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me output like this : https://prnt.sc/n3h35j

Please help me if anyone has some idea about this.

Comment: But i want to add it in block.

Comment: means i don't understand

Comment: Can we add this code in static block ?

Comment: Yes, exactly same

Comment: I added this code in static block and got this output : http://prntscr.com/n4jw9r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Following way...

Create Block file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class ShoppingCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get quote object associated with cart. By default it is current customer session quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
}
```

Call in template(.phtml) file,

```
<?php
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$_item->getProductId().'<br/>';
    echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName().'<br/>';
    echo 'Sku: '.$_item->getSku().'<br/>';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQty().'<br/>';
    echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br/>';
    echo 'Product Type: '.$_item->getProductType().'<br/>';
    echo 'Discount: '.$_item->getDiscountAmount();echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: i think issue in implementing

Comment: Hello.. your code works fine when i disable page cache. But when page cache is enable it doesn't show any item in cart.

Comment: You can create extension for that and create block file also phtml file create like above my code

Comment: I cannot get this to work in Magento 2.3.3 or 2.3.4.  There is a double semi-colon in the quote code above but that isn't it.  It just returns a blank page.  I see one comment about disabling the page cache but I can't seem to add that in the right place in my XML file.  Any thought's?